# Entity Framework 6: getting the simple stuff to work

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I've got a C#.NET (4.5.2) project that I'm trying to use Entity Framework (6.0) to manage my data model in a database.  That's what EF is for, after all.

I followed the examples here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx

But they're all for EF 4.1, and none of the syntax in those examples is working for me.  My conclusion is that something changed in the intervening versions, but I could be wrong; I've never used EF before, and since I'm able to get essentially nothing in it to work, I thought someone here might be able to point out what's probably an obvious error to an experienced eye.

First things first, I've got a Context class:

```
class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Announcement> Announcements {get; set;}
}
```

And I've got a second class that tries to use that Context to grab data from my model.

```
public List<Announcement> AllAnnouncements {
    get{
        using (var db = new DatabaseContext())
        {
            var results = from a in db.Announcements select a;
            var records = results.ToList();
            return records;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**First problem:** 
The `db.Announcements` in the second block has VS's red squiggly error line, and on hover, it says `Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'DbSet<Announcement>'.  'Select' not found.`

That tells me that the problem might be in the first block (where I set up the Context class), but if so I have no idea what it might be; I used the syntax in the documentation/examples, so I'm not sure what's correct if the docs are incorrecct.

**Second problem:**
All of the examples I've found completely ignore the topic of ordering, but I want these records to be ordered in most-recent-first order (so 'AnnouncmentDateTime desc' from a SQL perspective).  I notice that there seems to be an `orderby` string that's recognized in the LINQ string if I want to include it, and that there's a recognized `descending` keyword that presents itself as well.  But it's not clear where to put that, how to punctuate it (if at all), and how to get the query to run at all (this second point might resolve itself naturally if the DbSet were queryable at all, I won't know until the First Problem is resolved).

I know this is a rudimentary question, but the documentation I've been able to find doesn't work, and the questions here on SO make it clear that others have gotten *way* past this point in their own code, so I must be doing something wrong that would be obvious to someone who had used EF before.

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can give me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS is going to show the `return null` as unreachable code because you have a return statement before that. So just remove the return null part.

For ordering the records, you can use the `orderby` keyword in your LINQ statement.

```
var results = from a in db.Announcements orderby a.AnnouncementDate descending select a;
```

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that error right away and fixed it (I included a very-much-cribbed-down version of my getter).  But the problem is that db.Announcements appears to not be queryable at all.  Thanks for the syntax example for the ordering, but the select without ordering will not work either.

Comment: Actually, it's reachable because the 'using' block might not do anything, so VS isn't complaining about that.

Comment: Yes, the one I included in my post ("Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type "DbSet". "Select" not found.")

Comment: I copied and pasted your code and it is compilable for me. When you comment out your property, Are you still getting the error ?

Comment: This is one of dozens of similar errors I'm getting, this was just the smallest/simplest example of trying to get literally any query to be compilable.

Comment: Can you let me know what 'using' statements you have in the file that's compilable after copy/pasting this code?

Comment: Interesting thing: when I add the 'orderby' clause, the red squiggly error line *moves* from the 'in' clause to the 'orderby' clause.  I find this highly confusing.

Comment: I Think some other part of your cod is giving you trouble. comment out other code and try one thing at a time. You will be able to figure it out then.

Comment: Actually, it was the fact that I was missing `using System.Linq;` from the top of the file.  I found that suggestion in a different SO post.  But thanks to you for your help on this question!